# Behavior difference when casting NSNumber to Double in Xcode 8.2 and Xcode 8.3

Tags: swift, casting, swift3, nsnumber

In Xcode 8.2,

The following code causes a crash

```
let a: NSNumber! = nil
if let b = a as? Double { }
```

but this doesn't:

```
let a: NSNumber! = nil
if let b = a as Double? { }
```

In Xcode 8.3, both cases don't crash. What's causing the crash, and what has changed in Xcode 8.3?

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus Does that mean Xcode 8.2 still uses the old IUO type instead of attribute? Also, what's causing the first case to crash in Xcode 8.2?

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? (you can do `xcrun swift -version` and check if the "Use Legacy Swift" build setting is set to "Yes") The Xcode version isn't too helpful as, IIRC, Xcode 8.2 supported both Swift 2.3 and 3.0.

Comment: @Hamish Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1). Use legacy Swift is set to No.